# Alternative to make a div full screen

Tags: html, css

```css
.pop-up {
  z-index: 10;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 90vh;
  width: 50vw;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: #132c23;
  border: 5px solid #fffbce;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.wrap-pop-up-div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.pop-carousel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12.5%;
  left: 30%;
}

.close-modal {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 2%;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: #fffbce;
}

.close-modal:hover {
  color: #510000;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.pop-carousel .container-carousel {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}

.pop-carousel .slides {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.pop-carousel img {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.list-pop-up {
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
  top: 15%;
}

.pop-up ul {
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: rochester;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.pop-up ul a {
  color: #fffbce;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pop-up ul a:hover {
  color: #4c8d49;
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition-duration: 350ms;
}

.pop-up ul a.active {
  color: #4c8d49;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.pop-up ul li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.wrap-pop-up-div > .para-div,
.wrap-pop-up-div > a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
}

.wrap-pop-up-div > .para-div {
  left: 30%;
  width: 600px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #fffbce;
}

.wrap-pop-up-div > a {
  left: 7.5%;
  top: 80%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fffbce;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border: 2px solid #fffbce;
  padding: 5px 7.5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.wrap-pop-up-div > a:hover {
  border-color: #510000;
  background-color: #510000;
  transition-duration: 200ms;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}


@media (max-width: 950px) {
  .pop-up {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
   <div class="pop-up" >
    <div class="wrap-pop-up-div show-toggle">
     <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
     <div class="list-pop-up">
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a class="active" href="#">
         Badeparadies
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         Trieberger Wasserfälle
        </a>
       </li>

      </ul>
      </div>  
     <div class="pop-carousel">
      <div class="container-carousel">
       <i class="fas fa-arrow-left prevBtn"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-arrow-right nextBtn"></i>
       <div class="slides">
        <img 
        src="../source/img/gen-info/Rooms/bspForRooms.jpg"
        alt="roomForThree"
        />
        <img
        src="../source/img/gen-info/Rooms/bspForRooms.jpg"
        alt="roomForThree"
        />
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="para-div">

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde aliquid consectetur sit optio eius consequuntur porro similique ducimus magni id, sint, aut fugiat aliquam ab magnam facere ipsum cupiditate autem incidunt tenetur possimus excepturi accusantium nostrum. At fugiat ex natus ea ut id voluptates, vero, similique perferendis expedita tenetur esse.</p>
     </div>
     <a class="box-shadower" href="#">Buchen</a>
        </div>
            <div class="wrap-pop-up-div show-toggle">
     <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
     <div class="list-pop-up">
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a href="#">
         Badeparadies
        </a>
       </li>
       <li>
        <a class="active" href="#">
         Trieberger Wasserfälle
        </a>
       </li>

      </ul>
      </div>  
     <div class="pop-carousel">
      <div class="container-carousel">
       <i class="fas fa-arrow-left prevBtn"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-arrow-right nextBtn"></i>
       <div class="slides">
        <img 
        src="../source/img/gen-info/Rooms/bspForRooms.jpg"
        alt="roomForThree"
        />
        <img
        src="../source/img/gen-info/Rooms/bspForRooms.jpg"
        alt="roomForThree"
        />
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="para-div">

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde aliquid consectetur sit optio eius consequuntur porro similique ducimus magni id, sint, aut fugiat aliquam ab magnam facere ipsum cupiditate autem incidunt tenetur possimus excepturi accusantium nostrum. At fugiat ex natus ea ut id voluptates, vero, similique perferendis expedita tenetur esse.</p>
     </div>
     <a class="box-shadower" href="#">Buchen</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay show-toggle"></div>
```

I have some modals, which should pop up in full screen at 950px (max-width). Thus I implemented a media query but it does not work. Does anyone know an alternative way? I also tried to on my pop-up class a 100vw but this had no effect at all. Perhaps someone has an idea why? The code I post here is basically the way how I did it for my background of the modal (the greyish overlay), so it worked for me in this document already, seems odd that it isn't working now.

**CSS:**

```
@media (max-width: 950px) {
  .pop-up {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
            <div class="pop-up" >
                <div class="wrap-pop-up-div show-toggle">
                    <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
                    <div class="list-pop-up">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a class="active" href="#">
                                    Badeparadies
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Trieberger Wasserfälle
                                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        </div>      
                    <div class="pop-carousel">
                        <div class="container-carousel">
                            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left prevBtn"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right nextBtn"></i>
                            <div class="slides">
                                <img 
                                src="../source/img/gen-info/Rooms/bspForRooms.jpg"
                                alt="roomForThree"
                                />
                                <img
                                src="../source/img/gen-info/Rooms/bspForRooms.jpg"
                                alt="roomForThree"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="para-div">

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde aliquid consectetur sit optio eius consequuntur porro similique ducimus magni id, sint, aut fugiat aliquam ab magnam facere ipsum cupiditate autem incidunt tenetur possimus excepturi accusantium nostrum. At fugiat ex natus ea ut id voluptates, vero, similique perferendis expedita tenetur esse.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a class="box-shadower" href="#">Buchen</a>
        </div>
                        <div class="wrap-pop-up-div show-toggle">
                    <button class="close-modal">&times;</button>
                    <div class="list-pop-up">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                    Badeparadies
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="active" href="#">
                                    Trieberger Wasserfälle
                                </a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        </div>      
                    <div class="pop-carousel">
                        <div class="container-carousel">
                            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left prevBtn"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right nextBtn"></i>
                            <div class="slides">
                                <img 
                                src="../source/img/gen-info/Rooms/bspForRooms.jpg"
                                alt="roomForThree"
                                />
                                <img
                                src="../source/img/gen-info/Rooms/bspForRooms.jpg"
                                alt="roomForThree"
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="para-div">

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde aliquid consectetur sit optio eius consequuntur porro similique ducimus magni id, sint, aut fugiat aliquam ab magnam facere ipsum cupiditate autem incidunt tenetur possimus excepturi accusantium nostrum. At fugiat ex natus ea ut id voluptates, vero, similique perferendis expedita tenetur esse.</p>
                    </div>
                    <a class="box-shadower" href="#">Buchen</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="overlay show-toggle"></div>
```

Comment: tried `top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0` ?

Comment: yes I get the same effect, it is just hanging in the top left corner. When I deactivate in the dev tool the only bottom and right there seem to have no influnence....

Comment: @Snake_py, why don't you use the handy html snippet tool in the editor to build us an interactive example out of your code?  "I tried that too and it didn't work" is best supported by evidence

Comment: @DanielFarrell I added a code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
max-width: 80%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

in your style for `pop-up`. Change your css to

```
@media (max-width: 950px) {
  .pop-up {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.pop-up {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 80%;
    border: 5px solid #fffbce;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

messes up your popup if your media query is active. Add

```css
@media (max-width: 950px) {
    .pop-up {
        transform: none;
        max-width: 100%;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
}
```

as well and it should be good.

Comment: Oh boy, thanks for the hand. It would have been one of the last things, that  I would have considered, the border.. O_O.

Comment: You are welcome, I'm happy I could help! CSS can be crazy :D